# issue with kinit after freeipa installation

Tags: kerberos, freeipa

I installed freeipa on centos7 - the installation did not throw any errors nor could I find anything unusual in the ipa install log file.  However, when I run the kinit command post installation, I get the following response:

**kinit admin**

```
kinit: Generic error (see e-text) while getting initial credentials
```

Any thoughts on how to go about troubleshooting this?

Edit:
In the /var/log/krb5kdc.log file, I see the following entry:

```
preauth pkinit failed to initialize: PKINIT initialization failed: Cannot read cert
ificate file '/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.crt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you are not using a smartcard in this case I wouldn't focus on the pkinit error.  I would instead focus on the kinit problem and to start off, I would ask to see your /etc/krb5.conf file - its a fairly small file.   krb5.conf is a complement to DNS in that it allows the system to see where the important Kerberos resources are on the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the installation on centos and kinit works fine (I had to ensure that I was specifying the correct domain name during the installation script).